# Is .net 4.6 inplace upgrade ? Then why control panel shows all the framework versions?

Tags: .net, frameworks, .net-4.5, .net-4.6

Is .net 4.6 inplace upgrade? Then why control panel shows all the framework.
For example:

```
Microsoft .net Compact Framework 3.5 
Microsoft .net Framework 4.5 Multi Targeting PAck
Microsoft .net Framework 4.5 SDK
Microsoft .net Framework 4.5.1 Multi Targeting PAck
Microsoft .net Framework 4.5.1 SDK
Microsoft .net Framework 4.6 SDK
Microsoft .net Framework 4.6 Targeting PAck
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDKs are indeed separate components so each version of .NET Framework has its own. That also applies to Targeting Pack.

Compact Framework is completely a separate thing, so it is also on its own.

So none of the listed one is a desktop .NET Framework that conflicts with .NET 4.6.